# Finding the distance between two sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U$ be compact and $V$ closed. The intersection of U and V is empty set. I need to show that $d(U,V)=\inf |x-y|>0$.

My idea: Since $U$ is compact, then it is closed and bounded. If $U$ is closed, then $U^c$ is open, and then $V\in U^c$. If $x\in U$ and $y \in V$ which is a subset of $U^c$, then $\inf |x-y|>0$

Is my way true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You state that $U$ is compact but you don't used the fact that it's bounded and I don't see how your conclusion for the inf follows from the fact that $x\in U$ and $y\in U^c$.

Comment: @JohnDouma you are right

Comment: @JohnDouma Doesnt it follow that if the intersection of U and V is an empty set, the distance between the sets must be something bigger than $0$?

Comment: No. You need compactness. Consider the reals minus the origin. Then $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ are both closed and the distance between them is $0$.

Comment: Not generally. The graph of $y=1/x$ and the $x$ axis don't intersect, but the distance between them is zero

Comment: @JohnDouma Can you please give me a hint how to solve this then?

Comment: I have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it is not true. Then $inf |x-y|=0$ so for each $n\ge 1$ we we can find $x_n$, $y_n$ such that $x_n\in U$, $y_n\in V$ and $|x_n-y_n|\lt \frac{1}{n}$. Since the $\{x_n\}$ form a sequence in $U$ and $U$ is compact, we can find a convergent subsequence $\{s_n\}$ that converges to a point $x\in U$.

If we can show that $x$ is also a limit point of $V$ then, since $V$ is closed, $x\in V$ contradicting that $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

For any $\epsilon\gt 0$ we can find $N$ such that $n\gt N\implies |s_n-x|\lt
\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. By our assumption that $inf|x-y|=0$ we can find $M$ such that $n\gt M\implies |s_n-y_n|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Therefore, for $n\gt max(M,N)$ $|y_n-x|\le |y_n-s_n|+|s_n-x|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

Therefore, $x$ is a limit point of $V$ contradicting that $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. It is the intersection of sets

Comment: @JennieDurham Yes. Thank you. I wrote \cup instead of \cap. It is fixed now. I made the original edit to fill in the details of why $x$ is a limit point of $V$.